# Flex4-How can i get selected image(MouseClick Image)from Array Collection using DataGroup

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder, flashbuilder4

Gallery in DataGroup, How can i Call selected image(MouseClick Image) this is my Sample code

```
 <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        import spark.components.Image;
        import spark.components.TitleWindow;
        [Bindable]
        private var myArray:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection([
            {image:'Assets/images/best_01.jpg'},
            {image:'Assets/images/best_02.jpg'},
            {image:'Assets/images/best_03.jpg'},
            {image:'Assets/images/best_04.jpg'}]);

        private function imageClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void   {
            var imgCount:Number=0;
            var image:Image= new Image();
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(image,this,true);

            image.source=myArray.getItemAt(imgCount).image;

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:DataGroup id="dg" itemRenderer="com.ItemRenderForHorizontallist" 
             dataProvider="{myArray}" 
             verticalCenter="0" 
             horizontalCenter="0" 
             click="imageClickHandler(event)">

    <s:layout >
    <s:TileLayout horizontalGap="20" verticalGap="20" columnWidth="180"  />
    </s:layout>
</s:DataGroup>
```

- this code work but i want selected image(MouseClick Image) any one help me ............ thanks*

Comment: Have you tried to see what `event.target` returns?  How about adding a click handler within the item renderer and dispatching a bubbling event?

Answer (score 0):

You're using imgCount to access the index of your ArrayCollection; however, you always set it to 0.

You could change s:DataGroup to s:List, then use the selectedItem property in your click handler:

```
image.source = dg.selectedItem["image"];
```

Comment: it is not worked                                               error:Multiple markers at this line:
-Access of undefined property selectedItem
-1119: Access of possibly undefined property selectedItem through a reference with static type 
 spark.components:DataGroup.

Comment: Sorry - you are right.  imgCount issue remains the same, but you could use s:List instead of s:DataGroup and access the selectedItem.